# How to manage multiple versions of a glyph?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am learning how to design a font but I don't understand a thing: if I want to create a glyph but in both regular and bold versions, do I have to create it once and then copy/paste and I manually increase it tickness? More generally, how to manage multiple versions (bold, regular, ...) of the font?

Answer (score 0):

In the very general sense, a font may be desired in several styles, such as italics, small-caps, and variants of weight. In computer fonts, when these are combined into a single font, they are termed as Multiple Master. Fonts are not always multiple master, or may contain any number of masters for different styles or combinations thereof. The requirements and limitations vary alot depending on the file format the font is being designed for.  For someone just beginning font design it may be simpler to find a font creation package that clearly simplifies the creation of different styles. For moving toward serious design, it's worth reading plenty about different font file formats, then shopping around for a software package that supports it.